# skipping the first column while renaming some cells

Tags: python, csv

I wrote this script but which renames cells in CSV file that contains part of specific word but
I don't want it to rename the first column , I want it to skip renaming it "but I need the first column as it is"

```
import openpyxl
bid = openpyxl.load_workbook("Stock.xlsm" , )
for sheet in bid.worksheets:
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for entry in row:
                try:
                    if ‘Orange’ in entry.value:
                        entry.value = "Orange"
                    elif ‘Lemon’ in entry.value:
                        entry.value = "Lemon"
                    elif ‘Apple’ in entry.value:
                        entry.value = "Apple"
                    else:
                        entry.value = "Fruit"
          
                except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                     continue
bid.save(“RenamedStock.csv")
print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<DONE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

Comment: Have you considered using `iter_cols`? [Documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols)

Comment: no , Im currently learning python by myself and I don't know exactly how to use it but I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just be looking for `enumerate`. Try this:

```
import openpyxl
bid = openpyxl.load_workbook("Stock.xlsm" , )
for sheet in bid.worksheets:
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for i, entry in enumerate(row):
            #if it is the first column, do nothing
            if i == 0:
                continue
            try:
                if entry.value not in ["Orange", "Lemon", "Apple"]:
                    entry.value = "Fruit"
            except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                 continue
bid.save("RenamedStock.csv")
print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<DONE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

Comment: didn't work at all, it produced a CSV file with gibberish texts . FYI  I don't think "i" will be set to zero in every row . don't you think ?

Comment: It will. You have a `for` loop for every row (which would obviously re-start from 0). I'm not sure why this doesn't work for you as it does for me (with dummy data). Maybe posting a sample of your Excel file will help.

Comment: @ray - Open your .csv in Excel and check the contents